# How to Call Get and Post API in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, post, get, flutter-dependencies

how we can access the Get & Post Api in the Flutter app. Today, most of the apps use remote data using APIs.

An application programming interface (API) is an interface that defines interactions between multiple software applications or mixed hardware-software intermediaries.

Get and Post Method.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

class callapi extends StatefulWidget {
  const callapi({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<callapi> createState() => _callapiState();
}

class _callapiState extends State<callapi> {

  List<dynamic> data = [];

  final uri = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

  void postdata()async{
   final responce = await post(Uri.parse(uri),body:{
      "title": "Anything",
      "body": "Post body",
      "userid": "1",
    });
   print(responce.body);

  }
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    apidata();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: postdata, child: Text('send data'),),
      )
    );
  }
  void apidata()async{
    final responce = await get(Uri.parse(uri));
    final jsondata = jsonDecode(responce.body) as List;
    setState(() {
      data = jsondata;
    });
  }
}
```

here is the post method

```
List<dynamic> data = [];

  final uri = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

  void postdata()async{
   final responce = await post(Uri.parse(uri),body:{
      "title": "Anything",
      "body": "Post body",
      "userid": "1",
    });
   print(responce.body);

  }
```

Comment: what's problem you are getting?

Answer (score -1):

your code is working fine I run this and did not get any error in it, make sure you added http package in your pubspec.yaml file
and import it like 
**import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;**
use **await http.get** instead of **await get**

```
  void getData() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(uri));
    debugPrint("Status code is: ${response.statusCode}");

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        data = jsonData;
      });
      debugPrint(data.length.toString());
    }
  }

  void postData() async {
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(uri), body: {
      "title": "Anything",
      "body": "Post body",
      "userid": "1",
    });
    debugPrint(response.body);
    debugPrint(response.statusCode.toString());
  }
```

*Happy Coding :)*